# jQuery: cloned element gets removed when the original element is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that is containing one input.
When a user is clicking on a button, this input will be cloned and the clone will be inserted after the original input.

The user is also able to remove the clone.

My problem is, when I remove the original element that used to create the clone, all cloned element are removed too.

I only want to remove the target input that the user is choosing.

Comment: Do you clone the id and/or the name too?

Comment: it looks like you might be cloning the data also, can you share the code

Comment: Please share your sample cloning code

Comment: I found out that I did some stupid mistake by remove with the class name.
Fixed it now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cloned element is not linked to the original element. What is more likely is that the selector you are using to delete an element has too broad a scope and so is deleting them all. This can also happen if you are selecting by ID and, as a commenter has suggested, you have cloned the ID to each element as well.

Without some code snippets, it's hard to fully diagnose the issue.

Comment: Yes, a mistake i made. Cause I remove by using class name, should have remove by using $(this). Thank you very much